# Equivalent of MATLAB "reshape" function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Assume `X1` is an array of size `(768, 1024, 9)` with some double values.

I want to write the equivalent of the MATLAB code below in Python.

```
X = reshape(X1, [768*1024 9]);
```

I have tried it using these lines of code:

```
X = np.zeros((768*1024, 9))
for i in range(768*1024):
    for k in range(1024):
        for l in range(768):
            for j in range(9):
                X[i][j] = X1[l][k][j]
```

But this is taking a lot of time in running since it has four loops. How to improve this and what is the best approach for this (without using loop)?

PS: Before answering please see what the Matlab code is doing. The python code should perform the same as Matlab by assigning X1 in X.

Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iE7dtvQ2BN1E_jBcTvThZ39_7IvgQGcm

Matlab output in the link is incomplete but you can get an idea from first few values.

Comment: Just a lil comment : `x[i][j]` will ALWAYS be equal to `X1[767][1023][j]`, no matter the I or j value. Trying to fix this problem, by understanding the relation between I and kl should help you optimize a bit (down to 2-3 for loops, with the same number of iterations)

Comment: Did you look to see if `numpy` had a `reshape` function or method?  Your use of `zeros` suggests that you have an idea of how `shape` works. Also why the `X1[l][k][j]` syntax?  It works, but doesn't MATLAB use something like `X1(i, k, j)`?

Comment: Please see the Question again as I have added a link in it where you can see the difference between the code in Matlab and reshape method in python. Matlab output in the link is incomplete but you can get an idea from first few values.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy can do this by telling `shape` what you want the shape to be:

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.zeros((768, 1024, 9))
X = X1.reshape(768*1024, 9)
print(X.shape)
```

Comment: This is nowhere near to the context. I have to assign the values of X1 to X and it should perform same as the code in Matlab which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think it's the same idea. I edited the answer to make the assignment from `X1` to `X` more explicit. Is this not what you're asking?

Comment: I just assigned `X1` to have all zeros so that I have something to work with. In your case you wouldn't do that.

Comment: Please see the Question again as I have added a link in it where you can see the difference between the code in Matlab and reshape method in python. Kindly help me out! Matlab output in the link is incomplete but you can get an idea from first few values.

Comment: In your Matlab code, you start with a 4X4X3 and end with a 16X3. In your Python code, you start with a 2X2X3 and end with a 4X3. I'm still not seeing what you want. Did you want `a[1][0][0]` to return the same as `b[1][0]`? After you've changed the dimensions you'll have to call them differently to access the same element.

Comment: Yes, I wanted both the value to be same. Using order = 'F' in reshape worked. I was missing that thing. Thank you for your help. This was my first question on StackOverflow. Hope to learn more from the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.reshape

```
import numpy as np
X = np.zeros((768, 1024, 9))
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 9))
```

The -1 in the shape is autofilled.

Comment: Please see the Question again as I have added a link in it where you can see the difference between the code in Matlab and reshape method in python. Matlab output in the link is incomplete but you can get an idea from first few values.

Comment: Use order='F' as a reshape attribute

Comment: This worked. order = 'F' was the thing I was missing. Thank you for your help. This was my first question on StackOverflow. Hope to learn more from this community.